# Remove External Links from WordPress posts Using add_filter() in Theme functions.php

Tags: functions, theme-development, filters, the-content, regex

We have been searching high an low for a plugin, code sample or example of how to remove all external links at the theme filter level but can't seem to find anything online.

We want to keep the external links in the actual post database entry but simply remove them using `add_filter()` inside the theme's *functions.php* file so we can add them again when we need to.

We would also need to filter out links for the domain the site is running on - these internal links don't need removing.

We want to remove the link but keep the text inside the link and output it without a link surrounding it.

We have made a start but can't figure out how to exclude internal links or keep the anchor text inside the post.

Any help, code samples, advice, tips or suggestions are greatly appreciated and I thank you in advance.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'filter_the_content_in_the_main_loop' );

function filter_the_content_in_the_main_loop( $content ) {

    if ( is_single() ) {
      $content = preg_replace( '/<a href=\"(.*?)\">(.*?)<\/a>/', '', $content );
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the correct approach, minor replacement needed! ..

Simply replace
`$content = preg_replace('/<a href=\"(.*?)\">(.*?)<\/a>/', "", $content);`
with
`$content = preg_replace(array('"<a href(.*?)>"', '"</a>"'), array('',''), $content);`

Comment: Hi Hassan.  Thank you for your reply.  Yes, this worked - many thanks!  Now, all we have to figure out is how to allow internal URLs and add an `if` function for our domain to bypass internal links from this `preg_replace`.

Comment: I forgot to ask, do you have a code sample for that `if` command?

Comment: I guess it requires a bit of research, .. will get back to this when I get some time! :)

Comment: an if function for your domain will not work as this is a regular expression. A more reliable method would be to load the content into a DOM/XM parser, HTML tags cannot be correctly parsed with regular expressions and only very primitive but not foolproof processing can be done